# Python requests sending Content-Length 0 in POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it really what it should be or is there some problem?

I am doing it simply as it is mentioned in the doc like this:

```
response = requests.post(path, client_id=self.app_id, client_secret=self.app_secret, grant_type="client_credentials")
```

Output of `response.request.headers` is

```
{'Content-Length': '0', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.4.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.3.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
```

What is the error I am doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not sending any POST body, so the content length is 0. The header is entirely correct. If you meant to send a POST body, set the `data` keyword argument, and/or use the `files` argument.

You appear to have tried to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded data as keyword arguments; put those in a dictionary for the `data` argument instead:

```
params = {
    'client_id': self.app_id,
    'client_secret': self.app_secret,
    'grant_type': "client_credentials"
}

response = requests.post(path, data=params)
```

See the [*More complicated POST requests* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) of the Quickstart documentation.